# What short story book had "story for telepaths"?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, telepathy

In 1990s I read a SF short story book named along the lines of "Worlds shortest science fiction stories". I am trying to locate that.

The only story that I remember definitively is:
Title page: "Story for Telepaths"
Next page: "You know what I am going to say."

Comment: Hi there! :) There's already good info in there, but maybe you could take a look at [these guidelines for story-ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, any recollection what the cover looked like? Was the book new or could it have probably been written twenty years ago? Stuff like that, to increase the chances of a successful identification. Cheers!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're describing E. Michael Blake's *[Science Fiction for Telepaths](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?77491)* (reproduced in full below)

> Science Fiction for Telepaths <sup>1</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>1</sup> <sub>Well, you know what I mean.</sub>

It was published in [**100 Great Science Fiction Short Short Stories**](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/666584.100_Great_Science_Fiction_Short_Short_Stories), edited by Isaac Asimov.